# Split date_start and date_end by hours on Metabase

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

I have table with a column "Begin At" and another column "End At" that represent when a task begin and when a task end i would want to have a Bar display which display the cuantity of tasks that are being done in a specific hour along an interval of time.

For example, from the following table

[image]

I would want to be able to see that from `07/12/2021 21:00` to `07/12/2021 22:00` there were 3 tasks being done (row 1, row 2, row 3).

And also as i will have several thousands of rows i would want to use the date widget from metabase in order to specify range of times.

I have been struggling with this from the last week, i tried to create auxiliar questions where to query after but finally my only succeed was to hard code the 24 hours from a day but then i was not able to use the time widget and i needed to specify the dates myself on the sql each time i want to check a specific day and also i only was able to check from 24 to 24 hours, not from for example 02/12/2021 6:00 to 04/12/2021 18:00

My metabase is running on a PostgreSQL database. Is this even possible on Metabase? If not what are your advices to build this? Other plaforms? Pure SQL? Python?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about `metabase` but from a PostgreSQL point of view this calls for the use of [range-types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html), specifically the `tsrange`/`tstzrange`, depending on whether you have time zone information or not.

So a query could be:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM "someTable"
WHERE
    tsrange("Begin At", "End At", '[)')
    &&
    tsrange('02/12/2021 6:00', '04/12/2021 18:00', '[)')
```

However I don't know how you would get the *'02/12/2021 6:00'* and *'04/12/2021 18:00'* out of your metabase user-interface.